# Transfer leveldb database to the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, leveldb

I'm building an application that uses leveldb to store customer data on the (node.js) server side.

When customers visit the site, I would like to send a bunch of their data down to the browser for performance reasons. Since leveldb runs in the browser as well through [level-js](https://github.com/maxogden/level.js) I figured I'd just create a [SubLevel](https://github.com/dominictarr/level-sublevel) for the customer on the server, write it out to disk, and then send it down to the customer as a file.

I haven't found any packages that manage this process, or any discussions of best practice. Is there a better way to synchronize data between leveldb and level-js instances?